# c# CSV text file to single string (or array or list ) then add to or alter each string and output to single string variable

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I am using C# DataGridView with multiple rows (which may vary based on user input ) to export to a plain text file this is the result :

```
CompName,PowerOn,thin,Storage,acceptLic,verify,SSL,c:\test\myfile.img,root,P@ssw0rd,192.168.1.100
CompName,PowerOn,thin,Storage,acceptLic,verify,SSL,c:\test\myfile.img,root,P@ssw0rd,192.168.1.100
CompName,PowerOn,thin,Storage,acceptLic,verify,SSL,c:\test\myfile.img,root,P@ssw0rd,192.168.1.100

//...and more lines if user adds more
```

What I would like to do is parse the file and load each line into a single variable which I would like to append to a command line executable for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mytest\Mytest Tool\mytest.exe" -n=CompName --powerOn -dmode=convert -volume=storage1 --acceptLicense --noVerification --SSL c:\Users\me\Documents\down\myfile.img system1://root:myPassword@192.168.1.151
```

So the question is how is this done ?

I have checked many examples and it's now starting to get rather confusing as to which method to use to produce the required result.
(StreamReader, StringSplit,StringJoin and more..)

I am able to get the contents of the file to build a List using :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\foo\stest.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        //but where to from here ?


            }
```

Am I on the right track her ? I would appreciate any answrs ..

Thank you Kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write some messy logic here for you, please check it and correct if my assumptions are wrong.

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\txt1.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            string[] parameters =  null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


                parameters = line.Split(',');

                builder.Append("-n=");
                int paramCount = 0;
                foreach (var param in parameters)
                {
                    if (paramCount == 0)
                    {
                        builder.Append(param + " ");
                    }
                    else if (paramCount == 2)
                    {
                        // your req seems you need static parameter here
                        // if my assumption is wrong, then correct your logic
                        builder.Append(string.Format("-dmode=convert "));
                    }
                    else if (paramCount == 3)
                    {
                        // your req seems you need static parameter here
                        // if my assumption is wrong, then correct your logic
                        builder.Append(string.Format("-volume=storage1 "));
                    }
                    else if(paramCount <= 5 )
                    {
                        builder.Append(string.Format("--{0} ", param));
                    }
                    else if (paramCount > 5)
                    {
                        //Correct the logic as per your requirement.                            
                        string sslParams = " --" + param + " ";
                        string[] sslParamvalues = parameters.Take(11).Skip(7).ToArray();
                         sslParams +=   string.Join(",", sslParamvalues);
                        builder.Append(string.Format("--{0} ", sslParams));
                    }
                    paramCount++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Mytest\Mytest Tool\mytest.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(builder.ToString());

                //p.Start();
```

Comment: .......WOW THANK YOU KINDLY ...THIS. is EXACTLY what I needed ... and wow its straight forward :-) I just need to fix up the index count BUT WOW I can't thank you enough :-) YOU ROCK !

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace called `TextFieldParser` that was built specifically to parse CSV data.  You could use that to parse your data from the file.

Some sample code showing how its used:

```
using ( TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser( fileName ) ) {
    csvReader.SetDelimiters( new string[] { "," } );
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    MyType entry = null;
    while ( !csvReader.EndOfData ) {
        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
        // Code to build an entry or perform other actions goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
    private string Process()
    {
        // You dont need this list
        //List<string> list = new List<string>();

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\foo\stest.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line== null)
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.

                // Process line Here
                 //string[] values = line.Split(',');
                //list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                builder.AppendLine(line);
            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);

            return builder.ToString();

        }
    }
```

To export to a file just use

```
        string treated = Process();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\foo\stestTreated.txt", false, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            writer.Write(treated);
            writer.Close();
        }
```